# Do we really need the tag [plot-explanation]?

Tags: discussion

The tag [plot-explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) is on almost 500 questions, about 30% of all of our questions.  Is this tag actually useful?

Tags that are kind of on the same line that I question as well:

- [plot-inconsistancy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-inconsistancy)
- [analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis)

I honestly think we're better off removing these tags and leave them with just the movie tag.  From what I can tell the tag **doesn't add any extra meaning to a question.**

Comment: Applied to that many questions, a tag becomes almost useless.

Comment: Donald's got a good point. I would vote to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

I think such overly broad tags like `plot-explanation` and `analysis` or `identify-this-movie` are not more or less useful than overly narrow tags, like `dark-knight-rises`. In the end a question can have multiple tags and one of them being a rather general tag (that usually describes the essence of the question pretty well) doesn't do any harm. In the end we got 5 tag slots to fill with useful stuff and they shouldn't just contain movie or director names but should range from broad to narrow.

A question should have as many (fitting, of course) tags as possible to gain as much information about it as possible. And if 30% of questions are tagged `plot-explanation`, this probably means that, well, 30% of the question on the site are plot explanation questions. It doesn't need to mean that the tag is too broad. More often than not a `plot-explanation` tagged question is indeed, well, a plot explanation question (likewise for `analysis`) and that describes its essence pretty well, apart from any specific movie tags (which are there, too, anyway). If you're interrested in `analysis` or `plot-explanation` questions, well, go search them.

You wouldn't dare to delete the `identify-this-movie` tag just because 30% of the questions have it, would you (beware, I'm talking about the tag, not the question category itself, which is a hot topic on its own)?

**EDIT:** By the way, `plot-explanation` is a totally different tag than `plot-inconsistency`.

**EDIT:** In the end I think the plot-explanation and analysis questions make up the best and most important questions on the site and should be the signboard of this site. Once those tags are removed, how would you e.g. differentiate *"how did Ethan know Jim was the mole?"* and *"was the usage of Job a symbol for Ethan's desperate situation?"* from *"wasn't it a bit dumb from Jim to steal the bible, sounds like a mere plot-device?"* and *"what edition of the bible was used in this scene?"* if they're all only tagged `mission-impossible` (or maybe, even worse, `brian-de-palma`)?

Comment: `plot-explanation` is much better than overly narrow tags. +1 for this.

Comment: This.  This is the point I want to make but didn't know how to word it.

Answer (score 2):

For [plot-explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation), having that many questions tagged is a warning sign that the tag is too generic to be useful. I say we delete it.

On the other hand, [plot-inconsistency](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-inconsistency) is much more reasonable in number and so actually means something. We should leave it.

[analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) doesn't even seem like it says anything useful. I vote to remove it.

Comment: To me i don't see any functional different between plot-explanation and plot-inconsistancy.  Care ot giv eme a reason why you think we chould keep the latter?

Comment: plot inconsistency is a specialized type of plot explanation. The problem with [tag:plot-explanation] is that it is so general that it doesn't really mean anything, where as [tag:plot-inconsistency] is specific enough that the tag is much more meaningful and useful. It's like the difference between saying that something is an animal and saying it's a sheep.

Comment: agree with you , we should keep `plot` and `plot-inconsistency` tag and delete `plot-explanation` and `analysis`

Comment: Well, `analysis` says it pretty well. The question is about the deeper meaning of a movie or aspect of the movie (not all questions are, and those that are are described pretty well with the `analysis` tag). In the end just removing a tag because it has too many questions associated with it is pretty ridiculous. You got 5 tag slots to cover broad to narrow tags, and I don't want to see them all littered with just movie and director names.

Comment: @Donald.McLean Well, if I'm interrested in all animals and not just sheep but don't care about cars, then I guess I have a problem.