# Tag definitions - why do we buck SE's rules?

Tags: discussion

When someone creates a new tag, they typically use a synopsis for the excerpt.  Case in point; this excerpt for Game of Thrones:

> HBO TV series based on George R R Martin's "A Song of Ice and Fire"
>   books.

Now, by definition, there's actually a Reject reason for tag wikis that states the excerpt doesn't contain *usage* for the tag.

On every other SE site I know of, the excerpt in this case should read:

> For all questions relating to the HBO TV Series based on George RR
>   Martin's "A Song of Ice and Fire" books

Why does M&TV buck this trend, and should we start adjusting these excerpt's to comply with SE rules governing them?

Comment: I don't think it's really so much that we actively *"buck"* this trend, feel free to change 'em. But really, just precluding a *"for all questions about..."* before all of those tag descriptions doesn't really change much at all. For movie tags the usage seems pretty obvious. There are way other tags that need actual usage guidelines, and many of them also have it (granted, not all).

Comment: SciFi and Arqade also buck this trend.  Since tags can only be applied to questions, it seems obvious to me what they are for.

Comment: I actually think it serves a purpose to start the tag excerpt off strong... if all excerpts start with "For all questions"... who's going to read them? Start them off with the actual content, not repetitive phrasing.

Comment: Related question on [meta.se]: [Should tag wiki excerpts include “for issues relating to”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116752/162011)

Answer (score 1):

While the collective knowledge from all of the other Stack Exchange sites on the network helps shape the rules for new sites, for the most part, other than the core Stack Exchange engine we all run on, we're free to implement the rules as a community using everything that has already been learnt as guidance.

Since there isn't a question on meta already about how our tag wiki excerpts should look and what they should contain, there isn't really a set rule for how this is implemented on Movies and TV at this time. [It is on my list of things to do here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7837/52800) - I've just been busy [trying to get our tags cleaned](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1733/5603) before we sort out tag wikis. Feel free to jump in and start the discussion on what our tag wikis should contain, if not - one will appear soon™.