# Star Wars Episode IV - A New Hope

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a lot of Star Wars tags - as per [the discussion on how how we use tags](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1733/5603) large franchises should be tagged per movie with a main franchise tag. In this instance, we have [star-wars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) as the main franchise tag and we have a number of other tags for each movie:

- [the-phantom-menace](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-phantom-menace)
- [attack-of-the-clones](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attack-of-the-clones)
- [revenge-of-the-sith](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revenge-of-the-sith)
- [star-wars-iv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-iv)
- [the-empire-strikes-back](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-empire-strikes-back)
- [return-of-the-jedi](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-of-the-jedi)
- [the-force-awakens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-force-awakens)

<sup>Note: some of the above tags don't actually exist since nobody has ever asked a question about them...</sup>

The tag in question that I'm talking about, though, is [star-wars-iv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-iv). When this movie was originally released, the movie was simply called "Star Wars". It was only later that it was given an episode number and then even later that it was given an actual name - "A New Hope".

With this in mind, are we calling this tag [star-wars-iv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-iv) as it currently it, with all of the other movies given their release name as a tag, or are we going to use [a-new-hope](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-new-hope) for questions regarding Star Wars IV: A New Hope?

Comment: I will opt for name then number and make the numbering one synonym.

Comment: Anyways we never add franchise tag with every question about the film inside the franchise. We tag them with individual film tag until its about chronology or for whole franchise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Rename the tag to a-new-hope

I know the movie was released *Star Wars*, and only later given an episode number and then a name - but it's called by and known by its name now enough that there isn't going to be any confusion about using the name A New Hope.

<sup>Plus it's more consistent and we like consistency.</sup>